# What does "Always Allow..." actually do?

Tags: permission

That is, what files does it actually change? I am deploying a new version of an application on to multiple machines (100+) and when I test it on a machine, the "You do not have permission to use the application" box pops up, due to quite strict restrictions on the machine. If I click "Always Allow..." then everything works fine. However I do not wish to have to click this box on 100+ machines. Is there a command line alternative which can accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't work out what "Always Allow" does, I would suggest running something like [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to see what OS X changes. If it hits a plist file then you'll be able to run defaults on it.

I'm assuming its probably in the com.apple.applicationaccess.plsit. (But not tested)

Comment: Thanks! Using fseventer I found that it edits `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/[user].plist` which contains a master copy of com.apple.applicationaccess.plist.